# Computing double integral using linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> $$\iint_D (6x+2y) \, \mathrm d x \,\mathrm d y$$
>
> where $D$ is the convex hull of $4$ given points,
>
> $$D = \mbox{conv} \left\{ (0,0),(-2,6),(3,2),(1,8) \right\}$$
>
> This is a parallelogram with "unit vectors" $(-2,6)$, $(3,2)$.

I wanted to give a try to solve the following problem with algebra instead of calculus. So, I thought about calculating the area of it and piling it up to get its volume. I got the cosine between both vectors with the dot product formula, which is $$\dfrac{6}{\sqrt{13\cdot40}}$$ and the sine with the Pythagoras identity which is $$\sqrt{\dfrac{484}{13\cdot40}}$$ I remember that $|a|\cdot |b|\cdot \sin\alpha$ gives the height, and $|a|\cdot |b|\cdot \cos\alpha$ gives the area. So I figured that maybe this would solve the integral problem for the area?

$$\dfrac{6}{\sqrt{13\cdot40}} \cdot \sqrt{13} \cdot \sqrt{40}\sqrt{\dfrac{484}{{13\cdot40}}}\cdot \sqrt{13} \cdot \sqrt{40}$$

That gives me $$6 \cdot 22 = 132$$ That's wrong but the right result is $$11 \cdot 22 = 242$$ so there might be something in that?

Comment: You can compute an integral with the aid of areas if your integrand is 1 or a constant. In your case you have an integrand which contains other variables $x,y$... In this case you should decompose your domain and transform the double integral into two successive one dimensional integrals. Or change variables in order to transform your domain into a square (not sure that's easier to do...)

Comment: May be the solid volume of which you want to get is not a parallelipiped. Its top is not parallel to XOY

Comment: @BeniBogosel: would it work if I did a change of base from $$\begin{pmatrix} \begin{align} 3 & -2 \\ 2 && 6\\ \end{align} \end{pmatrix}$$ Sorry, I can't separate the 2 and the 6 properly!

Comment: Maybe if I made a cube of the integral then I would be able to calculate it's volume then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$\begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -2\\ 2 & 6\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} u\\ v\end{bmatrix}$$

where the determinant of the matrix is $22$. Since

$$6x + 2y = \begin{bmatrix} 6\\ 2\end{bmatrix}^\top \begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 6\\ 2\end{bmatrix}^\top \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -2\\ 2 & 6\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} u\\ v\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 22\\ 0\end{bmatrix}^\top \begin{bmatrix} u\\ v\end{bmatrix} = 22 u$$

we have

$$\iint_D (6x+2y) \, \mathrm d x \,\mathrm d y = \iint_{[0,1]^2 } (22 u)  (22 \, \mathrm d u \,\mathrm d v) = 22^2 \int_0^1 u \, \mathrm d u = \frac{22^2}{2} = 22 \cdot 11$$

Comment: This is amazing! So neat! I have to give it some thought to understand how and why the determinant comes into play. I'll be back!

Comment: Note that the gradient of $6x+2y$ is orthogonal to the 2nd column of the matrix. The integrand was not chosen randomly!

Comment: I have been thinking a bit about that, but why is that : $$\begin{bmatrix} u\\ v\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -2\\ 2 & 6\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\end{bmatrix}$$? Isn't it the vectors $u$ and $v$ that have coordinates  $\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix}$ respectively? And in addition, why is that $6x+2y=22u$? Where is that coming from?

Comment: I'm sorry that I still don't understand : why should I invert the matrix?

Comment: You mean: $$\begin{pmatrix} x,y \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -2\\ 2 & 6\end{bmatrix}$$?

Comment: Thank you again, I think it's extremely interesting. We did not write this way in our algebra class so I still get confused. Now I get the 22u. And that we need to write $$Det. du dv$$.  How do you multiply : $$\begin{bmatrix} 3 & -2\\ 2 & 6\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} u\\ v\end{bmatrix}$$? I am asking because in my class it would be: $3u-2v$ and $2u+6v$ and this is NOT our vectors. After this one I think I have no questions left!

Comment: But how do you multiply to get the RIGHT vectors in the end? You can't just put a column next to column $$\begin{bmatrix} u \\ v \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Aaaah okej so you mean: $$\begin{bmatrix} 3 & -2\\ 2 & 6\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} u\\ v\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} u,v\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 3 & -2\\ 2 & 6\end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: This part I get, the part I don't is how you are introducing u and v.

Comment: You have a parallelogram in the $(x,y)$ plane. It is a pain to integrate a function over this parallelogram. To make your life easier, consider a unit square $[0,1]^2$ in the $(u,v)$ plane. Via the linear transformation $$\begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -2\\ 2 & 6\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} u\\ v\end{bmatrix}$$ the $4$ vertices of the unit square in $(u,v)$ are mapped to the $4$ vertices of the parallelogram. Fortunately, the integrand in terms of $u$ and $v$ depends only on $u$. Thus, perform the integration over the unit square of the $(u,v)$ plane.

Comment: Note that the unit square in the $(u,v)$ plane is ($22$ times) smaller than the parallelogram in the $(x,y)$ plane. Thus, to compensate for the shrinking, multiply the integral over $u$ and $v$ by the determinant of the matrix (which is $22$).

Comment: I'm sorry for my gigantous response time, I really need to ponder over things!

Answer (score 3):

The area of the domain is given by the cross product of two sides,

$$(2,-6)\times(3,2)=22.$$

Then the integral must be the area times the average value of the integrand, which by linearity is also the value of the function at the centroid, $\left(\dfrac12,4\right)$, hence

$$22\left(6\cdot\frac12+2\cdot4\right)=22\cdot11.$$

---

Your answer cannot be right, because you make no use of the coefficients $6$ and $2$ in the integrand. What you are evaluating is

$$|a|^2|b|^2\cos\alpha\sin\alpha$$

which has no justification.

---

Another solution is by noting that the volume is a truncated prism with bases $(0,0,0),$ $(-2,6,0),$ $(3,2,0),(1,8,0)$ and $(0,0,0),(-2,6,0),(3,2,22),(1,8,22)$, which is the half of a non-truncated prism of height $22$. Hence

$$22\cdot\frac{22}2.$$

Comment: Thanks @YvesDaoust, I really love your answer! How do I find the centroid?

Comment: @Dovendyr: by symmetry, the centroid of the parallelogram is the centroid of the four vertices, i.e. the arithmetic mean.

Comment: I like your second take on it as well, but can you send some graphic representation??

Comment: @Dovendyr: sorry, no, your task.

Comment: I got an empty box. Even though I follow the instructions! Graphics3D[
 Prism[ {0, 0, 0}, {-2, 6, 0}, {3, 2, 0}, {1, 8, 0},  {0, 0, 0}, {-2, 
   6, 0}, {3, 2, 22}, {1, 8, 22}]]

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: this is a 2D cross-product, for which no standard notation is available.

Comment: @Dovendyr: do it by hand.

Comment: you mean to draw to parallelograms one over the other?

Comment: @Dovendyr: this is pretty trivial.

Comment: What I don't understand is that you are talking about a non-truncated prism. So when I did my prism, I am also supposed to add a plane that cut it in two?

Comment: @Dovendyr: $z=6x+2y$. It seems that you never used that information.

Comment: thank you for your patience, I am still trying to grapple with why that is making sense :). My drawing are horrific so it will be mathematica. Why the plane you described is cutting the prism in the middle?

Comment: @Dovendyr: draw by hand, you'll get a better insight (I don't care about your drawing, the exercise is for you).

Comment: I know... I just get a skewed tower with a paper in the middle...